# What is the usage of angular-tiny-calendar package in Angular (Not AngularJs)?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use angular-tiny-calendar package(npm) in my Angular project. I have followed the instructions from this page [angular-tiny-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tiny-calendar) to install the package. It seems this package is only for AngulaJs. Is there any way to make it work for Angular project. [Demo in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-calender101?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Answer (score 0):

### Most likely, no.

AngularJS and Angular doesn't have anything in common (besides the name).

They're completely different frameworks that fundamentally works in completely different ways.

You could try [ng-fullcalendar](https://github.com/jamaks/ng-fullcalendar) - it's a angular wrapper around the very popular jQuery library [fullCalendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I am looking for a small calendar where a list of events can be listed at the bottom of the calendar. Any suggestion apart from that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. Angular-tiny-calendar supports only AngularJs.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any similar package for Angular?

Comment: you can use the angular-material datepicker: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview